# How to execute a php link through cron job

Tags: php

I need to setup the following url to execute in every 5 minutes through cronjob.

http://test.com/app/collect-results.php?interval=15

Could someone please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: This completely depends on your server setup - are you on Linux, Windows, etc...?

Comment: @danmullen wording cornjob is not windows (:

Comment: Yes @donald123, I'm aware of that.  But given the author's lack of knowledge on "cron jobs", it's entirely possible he could have meant "scheduled task" or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a url with cron job, you need a program to get that url. In PHP it is possible by using either `wget` or `curl`.

You can use `cURL` like shown below.

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://test.com/app/collect-results.php?interval=15
```

With `wget`, set cron job like

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://test.com/app/collect-results.php?interval=15
```

Answer (score 0):

Chron jobs depend on your server configuration, sometimes you don't really have access to that or webhosters don't want to give you access. However I have been implementing this woraround for years:

In your site database create a table for chronjobs you want to schedule. You should have `chronjob`(the file to be run - ex. some_chron.php), `lastExecutionDate`, `nextExecutionDate`.

Then create a php file (let's say `chronjobs.php`) where you fetch the contents of the table you just created and test if it's time to execute the specific chronjob or not.

`if ($row['nextExecutionDate'] >= $today) {
  include(row['chronjob']);
}`

Then update the `lastExecutionDate` and `nextExecutionDate` accordingly. Have your `chronjobs.php` file included in each page (or wherever you want it to be triggered). You surely close your database session in each file anyway, so make sure the you put it before `$db = null;` or `mysql_close($link);` or whatever you're using.

So next time a user opens your site, even though the script hasn't been executed yet, it will be if the scheduled date is greater than or equal to the current time.

Hope this helps and gives you an idea :) Don't forget to accept or vote up if it's been useful.